# Mutual Authentication / two way SSL & OAuth

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, oauth2, ssl

Could you kindly help with following API authentication related questions:

1. Would Mutual Authentication / two way SSL described in this [link](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_forcecom_security_two_way_mutual_auth.htm)  works in combination with [OAuth](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com) authentication?
2. Does Mutual Authentication work with REST API too?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Bhannu ,                                                                                                            Please find the link below for your answer :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378127/are-oauth2-and-ssl-enough-to-secure-an-api

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Mutual Authentication & Oauth are two different authentication mechanistic.

**Mutual Authentication:** Allows client and server to identify and authenticate each other by using certificates. 
Ref: http://www.aboveandbeyondcloud.com/mutual-authentification-salesforce/

**OAuth:** also identify and authenticate user but using user/pass on salesforce site, so user do not need to reveal his password to 3rd part application. 
Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

And yes, once the authentication is done we can consume any API (REST, SOAP, Bulk ..etc)